# Start Flutter Desktop In The Size Of Screen

Tags: flutter

When using [Windows_Manager](https://pub.dev/packages/window_manager) and [UI](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/dart-ui-library.html) to make the app take the entire screen, I get the following error:

```
Invalid constant value.
```

Here is the code:

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:window_manager/window_manager.dart';


void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
     Size logicalScreenSize = ui.window.physicalSize;
  WindowOptions windowOptions = const WindowOptions(
    size:  logicalScreenSize,                        //Error in this instruction
    center: true,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    skipTaskbar: false,
    titleBarStyle: TitleBarStyle.hidden,
  );
  windowManager.waitUntilReadyToShow(windowOptions, () async {
    await windowManager.show();
    await windowManager.focus();
  });
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

I tried to combine most of the proposed solutions here but non of them works.

**EDIT**

The previous error has been resolved, but the app is still not taking the size of the screen!!

Answer (score 1):

So, the issue is, the `logicalScreenSize` variable is not constant means the the value will not be same that's why you can't assign that to const.

As I can you've did this

```
WindowOptions windowOptions = const WindowOptions(
    size:  logicalScreenSize,                        //Error in this instruction
    center: true,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    skipTaskbar: false,
    titleBarStyle: TitleBarStyle.hidden,
    windowButtonVisibility: false,
  );
```

Now you just need to delete const from first line

```
WindowOptions windowOptions = WindowOptions(
....
```

I removed const from `WindowOptions`

**SIZE NOT WORKING**

You need to assign `minimumSize` as well

```
WindowOptions windowOptions = const WindowOptions(
minimumSize: logicalScreenSize,
    .....
  );
```

Comment: The error is fixed but the application is not taking the size of the screen.

Comment: you can check. answer updated

Comment: I tried adding minimumSize, maximumSize and some fixed sizes, but apparently non of that is working!!

Answer (score -1):

Remove this `const` and try and run

[image]